# How to use static typed parameter in Python

Tags: types

I'm beginner of Python and getting trouble with using Python style coding.

To explain what I want to implement with Python, I made some Example class with Java.

```java
public final class Example {
    private int a;
    private String b;
    private Example ex;
    private ArrayList<Example> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public int example(Example ex) {return -1};
}
```

In Java it is possible to make Example type member variable and can pass Example type parameter. How can I implement this in Python? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't enforce argument types in python afaik, but you can use the `isinstance` function inside the body. Example:

```py
def class_func(self, ex: Example): # This is type hinting, it doesn't do anything functional
    if isinstance(ex, Example): 
        # do stuff

    else:
        # raise errors or return or whatever
```